# zend framework - hidden element has no value even when specifying it

Tags: zend-framework, element, hidden

I create a hidden element that way:

```
$this->addElement('hidden', 'id', '1');
```

but what I get is this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="" id="id" />
```

I've also tried like this:

```
$this->addElement('hidden', 'id', array(
    'value' => 1
));
```

but it didn't work better.

What's wrong?

Comment: Your second example should work as I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: So the reason is not this code. You must be doing something, somewhere in your code that causes problems. Without more info, its difficult to say what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys.
I've found the problem was indeed due to a isValid issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be using

```
$form->populate($someData);
```

or

```
$form->isValid($someData);
```

somewhere in your code ;)

Comment: Thanks. I started looking around in the other methods and there was indeed a problem of that kind.

Comment: Yes.  isValid has the tendency to clear the form and a custom populate method can screw things up pretty good with defaults

Answer (score 1):

You can use the setValue method of Zend_Form.

Try it like this:

```
$this->getElement('your-name')->setValue(1);
```

Comment: @softwareplay setVlue() does exit, please refer to documentation: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.forms.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to put in your form class:

```
public function populate(array $values) {
    parent::populate($values);
    $this->addElement('hidden', 'hidden');
    $el = $this->getElement('hidden');
    $el->setValue(1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps before render you do `$form->setValue()` and param id is null.

Comment: No. I don't have a $form->setValue().
 I checked, the method doesn't even exist.

Comment: @ndefontenay then your second example is right. Without code difficult say something.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me (zf 1.1) with an int or a string, but have you tried passing the value as string?:

`$this->addElement( 'hidden', 'id', array('value'=>'1') )`

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple:

```
//$form <- is your zend form element;
$form->get('element_name')->setValue(1);
```

Worked for me! :)

As those before me said: make sure that there are no form elements setters in your way (populate, setValues, etc). :)

Answer (score 0):

After problem with this I used (In form class)

```
$hidden = $this->createElement('hidden','hiddenElement');
$hidden->setAttrib('xxx','my value');
$this->addElement($hidden);
```

Extract value with

```
$form->hiddenElement->getAttrib('xxx');
```

It migth not be an optimal solution but it workked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setDefault?

```
$this->addElement( 'hidden', 'id', array(
    'default' => 1
) );
```